# How to open HTML file as words not codes using notepad++?

Tags: html, notepad++

I have article saved as HTML Formula and when I open that article by notepad++, the notepad++ open the article as codes not as words like that
(`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  <meta HTTP-equiv="Content-Type" content=" text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ doesn't support visual editor for html files.
It's just a kind of source code editor something like visual studio code.
But you can see the html formula with dreamweaver, webstorm and so on since they support visual editor for html files.